# How can I left align text in multiple paragraphs with full justify from Horizontal alignment

Tags: corel-draw

[image: Full Justify and Force Justify examples image without text frame]How can I left align text in multiple paragraphs with full justify from Horizontal alignment. the attached image refer to the challenge I am currently facing.

[image]

Please help with expertise comments to solve the challenge.

Comment: If I am understanding your question. You are using "Force Justify" while you should use "Full Justify" while you should use "Full Justify".

Comment: Hi hsawires, Thanks for your answer. I have added one more image to clarify Full and force justify challenge. This text is without text frame because I need to squeeze text manually for multiple pages. And I need paragraph line should be full justify as in last line of full justify paragraph.

Please share if you have any other idea for this. This can be helpfull.

Comment: I need to do this text justify without **text frame** (Artistic Text) not in text frame area (Without outer frame).

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible for Artistic Text as the artistic text is not designed to Handel large paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The only effect that cause this problem is the presence of the manual line breaks  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of paragraph breaks <kbd>ENTER</kbd> only.

To show up those breaks you should go to `Text > show Non-Printable Characters` or just click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

you should see something like that

[image]

So to fix that problem you should replace `the manual line breaks` into `paragraph break` manually or using an online tool doing the job for you like [Line Break Removal Tool](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php)

Or just copy past your text into any text editor and find and replace for special charater as CorelDraw didnt support finding and replacing for special character.